# Calling Amadeus enterprise-ws SOAP service with Postman or NodeJS

Tags: soap, amadeus

I want to call Amadeus enterprise-ws SOAP with Postman could you please help me to call it?
Or call with Node.js app

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @maziar, for questions about Enterprise APIs, you need to contact with  the Enterprise Account Manager in charge of your company. He will help you for sure. In this channel we only offer support for Self-Service APIs.

Comment: Besides, you can use the following document: https://developers.amadeus.com/support/contact-us-enterprise